# Bypass Cloudflare's captcha with headless chrome using puppeteer on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer, cloudflare

Im trying to access a site with headless chrome using puppeteer on Heroku. My setup works when I try it locally on my machine, but when trying it mounted on Heroku I get something like this:
[image]

I understand that puppeteer comes with javascript enabled by default and for what [I've read](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4696#issuecomment-511243772) it looks like it has nothing to do with that.

Im using [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth), [random-useragent](https://github.com/skratchdot/random-useragent) and viewport randomization but nothing seems to work.

Could it be that puppeteer and/or chrome is adding extra stuff when running locally vs on Heroku?

Here's my setup:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
const randomUseragent = require('random-useragent');

const USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36';


let browser = await puppeteer.launch(
  { headless: true, executablePath: process.env.CHROME_BIN || null, args: [
    '--enable-features=NetworkService', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
  ], ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, dumpio: false}
);
let page = await browser.newPage();
const userAgent = randomUseragent.getRandom();
const UA = userAgent || USER_AGENT;

//Randomize viewport size
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    height: 3000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    hasTouch: false,
    isLandscape: false,
    isMobile: false,
});

await page.setUserAgent(UA);
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.goto('https://external.site.example', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

...
```

Comment: ip address may be detected as "into the cloud"

Comment: you can try to dockerize you script locally and then, when it works, it should work remotely on heroku. and if it does not work its related to network.

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO I see. I thought that might be the case, because I tried dockerizing and got the same outcome. I'll try changing something network-related. Maybe using a proxy?

Comment: an anonymous proxy installed on your local computer should work since it works on local. but cloudflare is specifically fighting against bots so you will always end up with new difficulties :) good luck

Comment: Cloudflare definitely know when traffic is coming from a datacenter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to fix my issue following Raphael PICCOLO's comment on how IP addresses might get detected. Nothing extra was being added or removed by my machine or Heroku, it was just the IP.

I used a proxy which required [proxy-chain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-chain) in order to avoid getting `net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES` error.

My code ended up something like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
const randomUseragent = require('random-useragent');
const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');

const USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36';

const oldProxyUrl = process.env.PROXY_SERVER;
const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);

let browser = await puppeteer.launch(
  { headless: true, executablePath: process.env.CHROME_BIN || null, args: [
    '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`
  ], ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, dumpio: false}
);
let page = await browser.newPage();
const userAgent = randomUseragent.getRandom();
const UA = userAgent || USER_AGENT;

//Randomize viewport size
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    height: 3000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    hasTouch: false,
    isLandscape: false,
    isMobile: false,
});

await page.setUserAgent(UA);
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.goto('https://external.site.example', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

...
```